# Android button onClick unknown event issue

Tags: android, android-button

When i am pressing the button in some devices it's showing `E/Sensors: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=1, code=330, value=1), And here i given my code.

XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clcik_efferct_blue_white_no_round"
        android:text="DONE"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_clcik_efferct_text_white_blue"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

JAVA

```
@BindView(R.id.button_done) Button buttonDone;

@OnClick(R.id.button_done)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_done:
                try {
                  PreferenceManager.getInstance().setLocationName(localityName);    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: meaning some devices is other device it worked ?

Comment: i think it's better to add ButterKnife tag to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use butterknife injection library and add the plugin to your android studio.

Plugin - File --> Settings --> Plugin --> Browse Repositories --> Search butterknife and Install.